# Capybara element is not clickable at point with firefox

Tags: selenium, capybara, dc.js, clickable

I have a Capybara/Cucumber test running in firefox that will not click an svg element. I have the equivalent test working on other elements that are of the same type, but Capybara is telling me this error for this specific element:

```
Element is not clickable at point (1179.5, 172.96665954589844). Other element would receive the click: <svg height="124" width="290"></svg> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

The click looks like:

```
find("#partner-profit-chart svg g.pie-slice._1").click
```

And the actual site is hosted here http://mrr.devtechlab.com/mrr-dashboard.html, the element that it won't click is the third pie chart on the right. I am able to click the other pie charts just fine, but somehow Selenium thinks it will click the SVG containing the element for only this chart???

EDIT:
Ended up manually clicking the d3 element using the following(jquery click doesn't work on d3 elements FYI):

```
execute_script(
%Q(
  jQuery.fn.d3Click = function () {
    this.each(function (i, e) {
      var evt = new MouseEvent("click");
      e.dispatchEvent(evt);
    });
  };
  $("#partner-profit-chart svg g.pie-slice._1 path").d3Click();

)
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium attempts to click in the middle of the bounding box of an element.  The issue here is that with a highly concave shape the center of the bounding box isn't actually in the element, and therefore the click is going through to the encapsulating svg element.  Since this page is using jQuery, your best bet may just be to use #execute_script to find the element and trigger click on it.

Comment: Thanks, it's weird that the other pie charts work though. I've updated the question with the code to click the d3 element manually.

Comment: It all depends how much of the circle the segment you're trying to click on covers, the longer the segment the less likely the center of the bounding rectangle is going to be inside the segment, it probably affects the other charts too, just their segments are smaller

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.